# Television; female time travel police officer

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv

My friend remembers an older cop show where the lead is a woman that time travels to the current day.

The only other thing he remembers is that the cop got upset when someone wanted to shake her hand because in her timeline that was either how they have sex (or as intimate as sex).

Answer (score 6):

It sounds a bit like "[Demolition Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106697/)" with Sylvester Stallone and Sandra Bullock. There's elements of time travel (through cryogenics) and a female detective who wants to have sex **without physical contact** by using some kind of neural link.

Comment: I love that movie! I've been planning a rewatch since Taco Bell announced their US Taco Co and Urban Taproom. This was a TV show, My friend thinks he remembers seeing the main actress on the V reboot, if that helps?

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by the recent question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55677/does-the-1988-scifi-mini-series-something-is-out-there-exist-in-different-vers), I wonder if it could be the 1988 miniseries "Something is Out There"--the female officer is an alien rather than a time traveler, but she looks human so you might have misremembered, and according to the summary [here](http://www.tvacres.com/aliens_tara.htm) her species procreated with their hands so an attempt at a handshake was a faux pas:

> A unique feature of Ta'ra's race were her hands. On her planet, hands
>   were the focus of sexual activity, so when Jack attempted to shake her
>   hand, it was an encounter of the no-no kind.

First episode is on youtube here (you can find others in the related videos section), see if you recognize it: