# Does the 1988 Scifi mini-series 'Something is Out There' exist in different versions?

Tags: something-is-out-there

I have always remembered this scifi '[movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134/)' from my childhood and could even recall its name.

I recently found it posted on Youtube and watched the 2 part TV mini-series again after more than 25 years. I somehow seem to remember a scene which was not in there. I specifically remember there being a love/sex scene between the two main characters.

Maybe it could have been implanted back then by my boyish crush on the attractive Maryam D'Abo but i remember it so well being in there because i had it on VHS and must have seen beyond 10 times.

After seeing it again i think it could have been at the end when they both escaped and survived the prisonship crash on earth by locking themselves in the prison cell of the xenomorphic alien. I remember it being in there but no other details of it except that they were in a confined space after a narrow escape from the alien.

Google lead me to some post saying that there is also a seperate movie version but i haven't found any other references to this. I guess it could make sense because the tv series got edited for younger viewing and the (straight-to-VHS?) movie didn't?

Can anyone else recall if there was a different version which had the love scene, or am i just imagining things?

Comment: Are you referring specifically to the Mini-series or the 13 episode TV series that followed it?

Comment: MrSkin says no; http://www.mrskin.com/appearance/343/18272

Comment: It should be pointed out that Mr Skin's website is generally pretty NSFW. Or so I'm told.

Comment: I was referring to the Mini-series, not the tv episodes afterwards, but it makes no difference.

There is no other version with said scene.

So i did image it. Weird. Or maybe a mixup with memories from some other movie.

Thank you anyway for your time.

Comment: She got nekkid and freaky in a film called XTRO and there was a very brief (blink and you'll miss it) topless scene in "Something out there" but no love scene at all. From what I've read, the aliens procreate with their hands

Comment: As Richard mentioned there was a TV series which spun off of it as well in which there were *flashbacks* to events not previously seen in the mini-series... **Perhaps those events happened there?** BTW, I caught all of SiOT on the Sci-Fi CH back when they would actually play SF programs and I remember liking it as well!  I should look it up and see if it stands the test of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mini-series ended up as a TV movie ( First two episodes edited together) in my country, so the OP may have seen the movie before the miniseries; the scene explaining that the alien humanoids have erogenous zones in their hands ( Not sex organs, just pleasure nerves, like the backs of the knees in Tenktonese women ) was in the movie, but not in the episodes. 
 And the D'Abo cousins - Maryam and Olivia - are both regulars in SF and very pleasing to the eye moreover.